# How to deal with lots of AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Twitter web app which allows people to follow/unfollow users by clicking buttons. The app shows 8 users on the screen, and each button sends an AJAX request (using jQuery) to a script on my server which does some stuff and follows/unfollows the user chosen. After this, the server sends a response with another user.

In this way, I am always showing 8 users to people but it is often blocking the server. For example, if someone clicks the buttons too fast (15 request/second) the server takes several seconds to return each response.

I need to speed up this process because when the server gets blocked, people have to wait some seconds to follow/unfollow more users.

How can I do it? Do I need to use another framework?

Comment: you are sending async calls?

Comment: You can try and implement Node.JS or SignaR on the server. Establish a link to the server and push messages as things happens. Doing so many AJAX calls will kill any server in no time.

Comment: You have crazy users. You should `.unbind('click')` when user waiting for response.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes I am sending async calls.

Comment: @ppumkin Do you think I could solve it implementing those frameworks? Any other way? Thank you

Comment: @malcolm Yeah, users want to follow all suggested people by the platform as soon as possible. I can't use that method I need to provide them a faster response

Comment: I'd agree that getting 15 req/sec is crazy - I'd look at that design.  Stop the user clicking the same button while waiting for a response.  You could also look at a timer on the button press that holds for a short period (say 0.25 s) and then if another button is pressed in that time, it adds that message to the existing message.  Or...  you could implement sockets I guess.

Comment: Yea. SignalR makes 1 connection to your server per client. And you can hammer it with micro commands as much as you want. But you need server 2012+ or Win8+ to get it going. It's amazing , with instant communication.

Comment: Thank you so much @ppumkin It's a pitty I cannot use it. I will have to try Node.JS Have you ever done something related to my problem with it? Does it work well?